Is there any value in models that have a larger out of sample RMSE than a standard deviation?
I am predicting y values from x values using various regression models, elastic net and partial least squares regression (PLSR). To quantify performance of models we utilize root mean squared error (RMSE).
We perform regressions on the whole of the x and y data, as well as a round robin style prediction (similar to cross validation). In this round robin style prediction essentially some percentage of the x and y data is left out, say 5%, the model is trained on the remaining 95% of the x and y data, and the remaining 5% is predicted. Then the next 5% of the x and y data is left out, and the remaining 95% is used to train the model and predict the reserved 5%. This is performed again and again until all the y data is predicted as if it was out of sample.
The concern I have is in regards to the RMSE relative to the standard deviation of y. When predicting y with the round robin method, the out of sample RMSE is always larger than the standard deviation of experimental y itself. When training a model wholly on x and y (NOT round robin style) the in sample RMSE is significantly smaller than the standard deviation of y.
From what I know, that means that when predicting values of y out of sample, guessing y as the average of known y's is more accurate than using our regressions, and that we should use less components/parameters/complexity.
Is there any value or validity to these regressions, even if they predict poorly out of sample, and have a higher RMSE than standard deviation?

Welcome to Cross Validated! If you perform the calculation below over the test sample, using predictions made based on the trained model, what do you get?
$$
1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y_{\text{in-sample}}
\right)^2
}\right)
$$
(If you think this looks like $R^2$, you are correct.)

When using the out of sample, round robin generated y, i get a R^2 value less than 0.

Could you edit the post to indicate how you got an negative R-squared? Did you use some modified formula?
